# Existential theorem - Lipshchitz

Tags: lipschitz-functions

I have to find out whether the equation $$y' = \sqrt{y} $$ by the condition $$y(1) = 1 $$ satisfies the assumptions of the Existential theorem.

Now I claim that the function is continuous around x = 1, which means then we have **one exact solution** for $y' = \sqrt{y}; y(1) = 1$. Is this enough?

Because if I go with the Lipschitz under assumption that $x = 1, y_1 = y, y_2 = 1$ I get:

$|f(x,y_1) - f(x,y_2) |\leq k(x)|y_1 - y_2|$;
$$|\sqrt{y} - 1 |\leq k(x)|y - 1|$$
From where I am not able to make any conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}},
$$
and by the MVT it follows that this derivative is bounded in a neighborhood of $(1,1)$. Hence it is locally Lipschitz.
Of course, since $y \mapsto \sqrt{y}$ is not globally Lipschitz, you can apply your theorem only to get a unique local solution.

Moreover, remark that the mere continuity of $f$ is not enough to ensure existence *and* uniqueness. However it does ensure local existence (Peano's theorem).

Comment: For "locally Lipschitz near $1$" more is required than $|f(y)-f(1)|\leq C|y-1|$.

Comment: Yes, but what I wrote is essentially (a bound for) the first derivative at $1$. And it follows rather easily that $f$ is locally lipschitz...